# How to vertically align bootstrap buttons with text in a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem with bootstrap rows. My buttons are not vertically aligning with my row text. Here's an example of the problem:

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">A</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <h3>or</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 text-left">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">B</button>
</div>
```

The text even hangs *below* the buttons if I make it any larger, like so:

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <h1>OR</h1> <!-- H1 now! -->
</div>
```

Is there any way to get the bottom of "or" to line-up with the bottom of the button text? Or even just have the text be centered with the buttons? Thanks!

**Update:** here's a JSFiddle, as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/Dk37C/1/ (you'll have to stretch the right side display to see the behavior)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h3>` has a margin set on it, so if it gets bigger, the margin top will stay the same but the size of the font will increase 'downwards'.

You could set the styles of the `<h3>` to match those of the button, i.e. the padding, the line-height, the font-size, etc.

```
.text-center h3 {
  padding: 11px 16px; /* Extra pixel top and bottom for border on buttons */
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**http://jsbin.com/UNAYOqU/1/edit**

Comment: Great! I'm not sure why I did my example with `<h3>`.  Random, brain must have been slowing down...

Comment: Well, I had both `<h1>` and `<h3>` in my example... but `<h1>` just happened to be what I went with in the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found an easy way using bootstrap classes for text and a button in an MVC View, but I am pretty sure the idea will apply where ever you can use Bootstrap.

Just put the same header class, for example h3, in the class attributes of both the text and the button.

for example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 h3">
    Mileage Reimbursed Travel
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 h3">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create/Add ","Create", "EmployeeMileage")
</div>
```

Comment: This just adds the h3 margin to the divs. This doesn't end up aligning the text with the buttons

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to use the **vertical-align** css property. [Here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/) is a good write up of how to use vertical align.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry, (i'm not saying this is the best solution but hey, it works) put the text you want to align with your button in another button, then use CSS to remove things like the background and the border and disable the button.  I use this solution every once in a while and it works great.